# Sencha Architect design time expression evaluation

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Can Sencha Architect evaluate expressions when assigning values to configuration properties at design time?
Example:

```
 proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'ajustes.getUrl()'
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The above is treated as string.